# Meteor - remove current user from list of users

Tags: meteor

I'm currently publishing a list of users within a group. Although this works I'm unable to prevent the current user from appearing in the list. How do I remove the current user. Thanks in advance for any suggestions and help.

Path: `publish.js`

```
Meteor.publish('studentList', function (group) {
  if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, ['teacher'], group)) {

  return Meteor.users.find({roles:'student'}, {fields:{emails:1, profile: 1, roles: 1}});

  } else {

    // user not authorized. do not publish secrets
    this.stop();
    return;

  }
});
```

Path: `studentList.js`

```
Template.studentList.onCreated(function() {
    var self = this;
    self.autorun(function() {
        self.subscribe('studentList')
    });
});

Template.studentList.helpers({
    studentList: ()=> { 
        return Meteor.users.find({}); 
    },
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your client side code you can exclude users whose user id matches the current user:

```
Template.studentList.helpers({
    studentList: ()=> { 
        return Meteor.users.find({_id: { $ne: Meteor.userId() }}); 
    },
});
```

Or you could remove it from the result on the client side by doing Meteor.users.find({}).fetch().someRemoveLogic().

Comment: Doing it in the publication won't help since the user object is auto-published. Excluding it in the helper is the correct approach.

Comment: Thanks. I thought it was something to do with Meteor.user() automatically publishing the current users profile. I just couldn't figure out how to remove it in the helpers. Thanks again guys.

Comment: The problem with this approach is it will always remove the current user, what if we only want the current user to be removed if it does not match the actual filters and limits?

Comment: Then you can add a check to reference the filters and use that as an input to the find() command.

Answer (score 3):

By default, logged in user's data is subscribed to the client side. There's no way of removing that subscription. Because under the hood `Meteor.user()` works from this subscription. If you need to exclude it from client side helper, you can make a query that excludes current user's data. An example would be like this

```
Meteor.users.find({_id: { $ne: Meteor.userId()}});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this problem when *finally* removing `aldeed:tabular` from our Meteor app. Here's an elegant server-side solution.

For a publication of a list of `Meteor.users`, perhaps paginated, add a special flag `forUserList` for each published document using the [cursor observe function](https://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-observe):

```
Meteor.publish('userTable', function(skip, limit) {
   //  ...checks and validation code
   
   const self = this;
   const usersHandle = Meteor.users.find({}, {
      fields: {
         profile: 1,
         ...
      },
      skip: skip,
      limit: limit
   }).observe({
      added: function(addedUser) {
        //  Add a flag so we know the users come from this publication
        addedUser.forUserList = true;
        self.added("users", addedUser._id, addedUser);
      },
      changed: function(changedUser) {
        self.changed("users", changedUser._id, changedUser);
      },
      removed: function(removedUser) {
        self.removed("users", removedUser._id);
      }
   });

   //  Mark the subscription as ready
   self.ready();

   // Stop observing the cursor when client unsubs.
   self.onStop(function () {
      usersHandle.stop();
   });
}
```

Then on the client you can pass a query to mini-mongo for the flag you added:

```
//  Cursor function
instance.users = function() {
   //  Set up the client query to make sure we only include documents from this datatable (as this can return
    //  ALL documents on the client). So this is best practice.
    const query = {
      forUserList = true;
    };
    const sort = {
      ...
    };
    return instance.data.collection.find(query, {sort: sort});
};
```

This will then only display the currently logged in user when they're actually *found* by the above publication. So if you're doing a paginated list of users, the currently logged in user shows up in the paginated list as normal and gets the `forUserList` flag and thus appears in the list. But when they are paginated over, the logged in user object will be missing the flag and thus won't appear in the template due to the mini-mongo query.

Using the cursor observer functions are very flexible and powerful for manipulating published documents.